# How to open PyDev perpective in Eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I just installed PyDev (version 5.1.1) on Eclipse Mars.2 (version 4.5.2). I would like to open the PyDev perspective but it is not listed:

[image]

Whereas in the Installation Details dialogue PyDev is present:

[image]

How can I open the PyDev perspective on this Eclipse version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev from version 5.0 onwards requires that you be using Java 8 to run your Eclipse. This is mentioned on the PyDev [home page](http://www.pydev.org/). Other parts of Eclipse Mars will run with Java 7 but not the PyDev plug-ins.

Comment: I have both Java 8 and Java 7 installed and apparently a recent system upgrade switched the latter to default.